# What is the difference between multiple regression WITH interaction, and WITHOUT interaction? (* vs + vs " vs : in lm)

Tags: r, regression, interaction, lm

I am attempting to set up a multiple regression model using "lm", but I am unsure whether to use :, + or * to indicate the interaction between multiple predictor variables.

?lm shows the following paragraph:

> A terms specification of the form first + second indicates all the
>   terms in first together with all the terms in second with duplicates
>   removed. A specification of the form first:second indicates the set of
>   terms obtained by taking the interactions of all terms in first with
>   all terms in second. The specification first*second indicates the
>   cross of first and second. This is the same as first + second +
>   first:second

However, I'm not exactly sure which one to use when I what a predicted value for a specific set of predictor values.

For an example from mtcars, let's say qsec is the predicted variable, with cyl, vs and gear as the predictor variables.  In order to find the qsec where cyl = 4 AND vs = 0 AND gear = 3, what operator should I use in lm? (* vs + vs " vs :)

Each operator, of course, yield different results using predict().  Example below:

```
#  +  operator
    model1 <- lm(qsec ~ cyl+vs+gear, mtcars)
    predict(model1, data.frame(cyl = 4, vs = 0, gear = 3))


#  : operator
    model2 <- lm(qsec ~ cyl:vs:gear, mtcars)
    predict(model2, data.frame(cyl = 4, vs = 0, gear = 3))

#  *  operator
    model3 <- lm(qsec ~ cyl*vs*gear, mtcars)
    predict(model3, data.frame(cyl = 4, vs = 0, gear = 3))
```

Comment: You can find *many* relevant posts discussing the meaning of interaction terms (and the R formula syntax) on Cross Validated and Stack Overflow; there are also plenty of tutorials available on the web that provide many more details. I think this question is too broad in its current form, and I vote to close.

Comment: Yes, sorry it's more a stats question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a model decision you'll have to make. When fitting a linear model, you have to make assumptions about the true relationship between the predicted variable and the predicting variables. The three assumptions in your case are:

- +: $qsec = \beta_0 + \beta_1 cyl + \beta_2 vs + \beta_3 gear$: The basis / standard linear model without interaction terms
- *: $qsec = \beta_0 + \beta_1 cyl * vs * gear $ : only interaction, makes little sense in most cases
- : :$qsec = \beta_0 + \beta_1 cyl + \beta_2 vs + \beta_3 gear + \beta_4 cyl*vs + \beta_5 cyl *gear + \beta_6 vs*gear + \beta_7 cyl*vs*gear$: more complex extension of the first one, including interaction terms

As they are three different models, they make different predictions. If you print out the models in R, e.g. with "summary(model)", you get more details regarding them.

Comment: The spirit here is helpful, but the wording is more problematic. I've edited out "implicit" as the syntax is explicit; it just is new to people to who it is new. Also, although I've left in the word "assumptions", I guess many would say the syntax here is about functional form; assumptions e.g. about stochastic error are something different. Feel free to reverse my edits if you disagree with them.

Comment: No objections from my side, if someone thinks of a better wording for "assumption", I'm always happy to learn!